# Massive data in postgresql with PHP

Tags: php, excel, postgresql, nginx, cakephp-3.0

Currently I have a dedicated server with more than 124 GB of ram, 12 processor cores, cpanel, centos 7 64 bits, cloudlinux, etc ...

I have a project in Cakephp where I import data using an excel file. This excel file usually has only 1,000 files. When I go through the script (Consult, update or insert) it takes between 20 to 30 min and then exit error 504 Gateway TimeOut.

I have configured the server with nginx, I have modified the time_out and still this error is still coming out. I have also modified the postgrsql configuration to share more space and memory but none of this works.

I need to know what to do so that I can solve the problem.

The table that I consult is a table that has more than 6 million records.

It should be noted that even though the error 504 goes out by reviewing the server processes, I find a running postgresql process. I need to know how to do so that the server does not exhaust the waiting time since at the end of this process the system tells me how many data were updated, how many and which ones.

Thank you

Comment: We need more information to help. Does the file have 1000 lines ? What logic did you implement to process each line ?
A server 1/10h of that size should process 1000 lines in a matter of a few minutes. Please edit your question and add the logic of the import action.

Answer (score 0):

Try raising the **max_execution_time** setting in **php.ini** file (usually  /etc/php.ini).

Also make sure that PHP-FPM **request_terminate_timeout** (usually in /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf) is set to the same value.

Verify that all nginx timeout settings are appropriate for your use case (i.e. you have proxy enabled, etc.), but at least check that **[fastcgi_read_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_read_timeout)** and **[fastcgi_send_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_send_timeout)** are properly set.

Reload or restart nginx.

Comment: Thank you. but apparently for more than ample the memory and others the problem or the slowness of the same one is in the SELECT of the postgresql since it is what in itself comsume 100% the resources.

How can I generate a script that can read all those records without generating or shrinking the select query?

Comment: You said you are inserting records, why is there a select happening? Assuming there's a reason for this, maybe your table doesn't have the right keys set up to make the select efficient?

Comment: first consult to validate if it exists. If the data exists updates, if the data does not exist it inserts. This process does it 1,000 times. The problem as indicated was the database since it already has more than 6 million records.

If I perform the test with another database it works perfectly even if I send it up to 60 thousand records I get a response.